# custom validation help (Mvc Foolproof )

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i have a DropDownListFor  `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Payment)` with values

- cash
- money order
  and i have TextBoxFor  `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PaymentType)`, i want to make the TextBoxFor Required only if the user select money order from the DropDownListFor,i have Mvc Foolproof and i was trying to use RequiredIf

here is my ViewModel

```
public string PaymentType { get; set; }
public string Payment{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: `[RequiredIf("Payment==money order"]`

Comment: waiting for your help :(

Comment: Its `[RequiredIf("Payment", "money order")]`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stephen Muecke

```
[RequiredIf("Payment", "money order")]
```